# Python minimum boiler plate class init

Tags: python, oop

There is a class in my project that is a glorified dictionary + error checking. I want to trim it down as much as possible: it uses `**kwargs` despite not inheriting from anything, and most of the class is made up of

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    self.attr = kwargs.pop('attr', attr_default)
    # Multiple lines like this one. 
    ...
```

So my question is, can I reduce all of that boilerplate without breaking the API?

My first thought was to use explicit optional arguments, which gets rid of the `attr_default`, but to get rid of the block of `self.attr` assignments, I want an `iterable` of all the arguments (which is no longer `kwargs`).

EDIT: The iterable is probably in the `locals()`.

Is this even good practice?

Comment: "Is this even good practice? " => it's always better to use explicit arguments names when possible - it makes the code more readable,  provides support for inspection (the builtin `help()` function, code completion etc), and will also catch possible client code typos.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Suppose I did that and used `locals()` to automatically update the class attributes, can I reasonably expect the locals not to contain anything from decorators and such?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).
It is an amazing solution to exactly this. The docs are great, too!

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class BoilerAway:
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
    another_attr: int


obj = BoilerAway("hello", "world", 42)
```

Naturally, these are object attributes and not class ones.
The core feature of `dataclasses` is that each object is lightweight and has a much smaller memory footprint than a regular class.

Have fun!